# proving $\left[\left(\cos(x)+1\right)+i\sin(x)\right]^{n} = 2^n\cos^{n}(\frac{x}{2})\left(\cos(\frac{nx}{2})+i\sin(\frac{nx}{2})\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I prove the following where i is the imaginary unit.
$$\left[\left(\cos(x)+1\right)+i\sin(x)\right]^{n} = 2^n\cos^{n}(\frac{x}{2})\left(\cos(\frac{nx}{2})+i\sin(\frac{nx}{2})\right)$$

Comment: **Hint:** $\cos(x)+1=2\cos^2(x/2)$ and $\sin(x)=2\cos(x/2)\sin(x/2)$. Then use de Moivre's formula...

Comment: Try using induction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\left[\left(\cos(x)+1\right)+i\sin(x)\right]^{n} \implies\left(2\cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2})+2i\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2})\right)^{n}\\ \implies2^n\cos^n(\frac{x}{2})\left(\cos(\frac{x}{2}) + i\sin(\frac{x}{2})\right)^{n}$$